# Which way should I choose to broadcast a topic in ROCON?

Tags: ros, communication, multimaster, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all! I am  establishing a multi-robot system with several turtlebots. Every robot is an individual intelligent agent and same with each other.  Then I want every robot in this multi-robot system to share their position. That is every robot has to broadcast its own position to other robots. I think it is easy to achieve this by using the pacakge [rocon_multimaster](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_multimaster)

Since every robot in our multi-robot system is same to each other, we has implemented a message topic /position_share which contains the information of robot_id and related information about the robot which publishes the topic /position_share.  Every robot in this multi-robot system listens to topic /position_share and judges which robots the current message is from and do subsequent actions.

However, checking the communication mechanism of advertisment in rocon_multimaster, I am confused on how to broadcast this topic message. Because for the same channel(also topic) /position_share. Every robot (move_base node) has a publisher and subscriber on it. So there is two ways to do this.

```
 default_advertisements:
         - name: /position_share
           node: move_base
          type: publisher
  default_advertisements:
          -name: /position_share
           node: move_base
           type: subscriber
```

Which way should a robot choose to broadcast its own topic /position_share?  As a subscriber or a publisher?

Obviously, for a receiver, it also has two ways:

```
  default_pulls:
        - gateway: robot_id
          rule：
             name:/position_share
             node: move_base
             type: publisher

   default_pulls:
        - gateway: robot_id
          rule：
             name:/position_share
             node: move_base
             type: subscriber
```

Of course, here I think I should add many gateways in which each of them represent a robot.

Here I am also confused about the type.  What should a robot to choose between "subscriber“ and "publisher" to receive the message /position_share from other robots ?
Looking forward to helpful advice, thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191883/which-way-should-i-choose-to-broadcast-a-topic-in-rocon?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-09-04**:
I think one gateway should suffice: http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_multimaster/Use%20Cases .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even in a multi-turtlebot individual agent scenario I'd still prefer the route of having a central master (e.g. on a pc). Note that this master doesn't stop p2p communications, it's just a landing bay for communication registrations that make it easy to introspect the robot to robot communications. There you can use all the usual tools like rostopic, rviz, rqt_graph, etc. In this case:

1. For sending messages via the central master registry, have every robot *flip* a publisher to the central share.
2. For listening to messages landing via the central master registry, have every robot *flip* a subscriber to the central share

Without the central master I imagine you'll have to do alot of ssh'ing around.

1. For broadcasting to all its own position share, you'd advertise your own publisher.
2. For listening to another robot_id's position share, you'd pull their publisher in.

You could feasibly achieve the same effect with subscribers instead, but it doesn't feel as intuitive. Publishers are also problem free - subscribers come with some fine print with regards to multimaster usage.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-10**:
Thank you very much! I will try your advices!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Either way should work.

You can flip the position_share publisher from robot A to system X, or you can flip position_share subscriber from system X to robot A.

In this case, a position_share subscriber node in the system X will receive position of robot A.

---

Originally posted by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) with karma: 634 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-09-10**:
Thank you for your advice and attention!